# How to read multiple values in one row from csv file to post body as variable in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

How to make an Post HTTP request Body from multiple values in a single column from a CSV file?
In CSV file, under the `transactional_currencies`, I need to insert two or more values as per requirement.
[image]

This is the Json Body need to pass in Post HTTP request Body

```
{
    "country_name": "${country}",
    "status": "$ {status}",
    "transactional_currencies": ["${transactional_currencies[0]", "${transactional_currencies[1]"]
}``
```

[image]``

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what did you ask but let's give it a try

You should define a delimiter character in your CSV dataset config element.

For example

---

Single Line in our CSV: sample@sample.com,testusername,testpassword

1. After adding a CSV data config to your project, open the configuration panel.
2. Choose your delimiter character as " , " since the line above has
   some commas.
3. Choose variable names as "email", "username" and "password"
4. Now you have splitted a single csv line into 3 different variables.
5. On your request's body, write these variables as ${email} , ${username}
   , ${password}

Answer (score 0):

Not with the CSV Data Set Config

If you have fixed number of entries in the `transactional_currencies` (i.e. always 2) you can use [__CSVRead() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) where you will be able to decide when to go to the next entry/row.

If the number of entries in the `transactional_currencies` is dynamic, you can go for [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and build your request body using [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/) as it's described in the [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) article

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
String path ="D:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Inssurely/Country06082021.csv";
File file = new File(path);
BufferedReader bufRdr= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
Integer i=1;

while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(line);
 String[] transactional_currencies = line.split(",");
 vars.put("transactional_currencies" + i, transactional_currencies[0]);
 i++;
}
bufRdr.close();   This is the code i have written in Beanshell sampler, But two values must be fetched.

Comment: This is the response body                                                                                              
 POST data:
{
  "country_name": "Pakistan",
  "status": false ,
  "transactional_currencies": ""2"
}          I need in transactional_currencies instead one value 2, I need two values eg. 2,4.

Comment: [Forget about beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) and try amending your code like: `String path = "D:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Inssurely/Country06082021.csv";File file =new File(path);BufferedReader bufRdr =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));String line=null;Integer i=1;while((line =bufRdr.readLine()) !=null){System.out.println(line);String[] transactional_currencies =line.split(",");for (int z = 0; z < transactional_currencies.size(); z++){vars.put("transactional_currencies" + z, transactional_currencies[z]);i++;}}bufRdr.close();`

Comment: I have to paste the above code in  JSR223 PreProcessor and build in request body using beanshell language or groovy language.